# Cannot load data from database to chart using extjs

Tags: spring, extjs

I'm using spring and hibernate to display an extjs chart from database. But, when I'm pointing out the url to the controller, it is not caling . Check my reference in dispatcher servlet

```
     <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="loadChart.htm">empCntrl</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean name="empCntrl" class="com.hclt.controllerr.Contrler" />
```

Script code is as follows:

```
  function loadChart(){
    Ext.chart.Chart.CHART_URL = 'images/charts.swf';
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['depname', 'count'],
        url: 'loadChart.htm'
    });

    new Ext.Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Employee Details',
        renderTo: 'chartDiv',
        items: {
            store: store,
            xtype: 'piechart',
            dataField: 'depname',
            categoryField: 'count',
            //extra styles get applied to the chart defaults
            extraStyle:
            {
                legend:
                {
                    display: 'top',
                    padding: 5,
                    font:
                    {
                        family: 'Tahoma',
                        size: 13
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: <bean name="empCntrl" class="com.hclt.controllerr.Contrler" />
You have serious naming problems. I wouldn't like maintaining your code! 3 different ways of spelling "controller", and not one correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've created the store it doesn't auto-load by default.

either add: autoLoad: true to the config of your store

or

call store.load() somewhere in your function.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried. It is not making a call to the controller. Reference problem is there?